# Adding multiple instances of taskStructures to the list without overwriting first item and display problems - C#

Tags: c#, list, data-structures

Big thanks to the people who helped me out yesterday, however, after many hours of trying to fix this on my own, I can't find the solution.

I have my taskStructure class with it's list shown below:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public class taskStructure
    {
        public string taskName { get; set; }
        public string taskDescription { get; set; }
        public int Priority { get; set; }
        public string dateAndTime { get; set; }
    }


    public List<taskStructure> TasksArray = new List<taskStructure>(); //Delcared a list data structure
```

And on my addTask form I have this to assign the rich text boxes to the appropriate variables:

```
    private void createTaskBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 welcomeForm = new Form1();

        welcomeForm.TasksArray.Add(new Form1.taskStructure
            {
                taskName = taskNameRTB.Text,
                taskDescription = taskDescRTB.Text
            });
        //Test outputs
       MessageBox.Show(welcomeForm.TasksArray[0].taskName);
       MessageBox.Show(welcomeForm.TasksArray[0].taskDescription);
       MessageBox.Show(welcomeForm.TasksArray[1].taskName);
       MessageBox.Show(welcomeForm.TasksArray[1].taskDescription);

        this.Close();
```

The inputs from the first set of [0] tests come up fine, but [1] throws the 'ArgumentOutOfRangeException',

So I did this:

```
    private void createTaskBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 welcomeForm = new Form1();

        welcomeForm.TasksArray.Add(new Form1.taskStructure
            {
                taskName = taskNameRTB.Text,
                taskDescription = taskDescRTB.Text
            });

        welcomeForm.TasksArray.Add(new Form1.taskStructure
            {
                taskName = taskNameRTB.Text,
                taskDescription = taskDescRTB.Text
            });
        //Test outputs
       MessageBox.Show(welcomeForm.TasksArray[0].taskName);
       MessageBox.Show(welcomeForm.TasksArray[0].taskDescription);
       MessageBox.Show(welcomeForm.TasksArray[1].taskName);
       MessageBox.Show(welcomeForm.TasksArray[1].taskDescription);

        this.Close();
```

And now it works, however, the values I enter for [0] also are in [1].

I have also tried a foreach to get them to output:

```
        foreach (taskStructure task in TasksArray)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(task);
        }
```

But I get a: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(string)' has some invalid arguments

So my questions are: How do I add multiple items without them overwriting the first task that I enter? and how do I get it to output all of them to see if they are being stored correctly?

**Basically: I want to add a task, save it to the list, add another task, save that to the list etc. etc. and then output them all to the user.**

Kind Regards,

Kieran

Comment: How are you adding more test outputs, with what values?  Your `MessageBox.Show(task)` will throw that error since `task` is not a String, so you should maybe override the `ToString()` in your class and output a custom string output and then call `MessageBox.Show(task.ToString())`

Comment: Like this: `welcomeForm.TasksArray.Add(new Form1.taskStructure
                {
                    taskName = taskNameRTB.Text,
                    taskDescription = taskDescRTB.Text
                });
MessageBox.Show(welcomeForm.TasksArray[0].taskName);
MessageBox.Show(welcomeForm.TasksArray[0].taskDescription);
MessageBox.Show(welcomeForm.TasksArray[1].taskName);
           MessageBox.Show(welcomeForm.TasksArray[1].taskDescription);
`
I tried what you offered, and the error no longer happens, but now when I click on the button to show them, it's not working. Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: Please update the question with that code, it will get lost in the comments later and is harder to read :)

Comment: Do the values of `taskNameRTB.Text` and `taskDescRTB.Text` change between the two `TaskArray.Add` calls? I am suspecting that you are seeing two instances of the the same data and this leads to the belief that they are not being set correctly

Comment: I'm sorry still new to this forum :P I have updated my question with the new code and problems :) And I'm new to this really, so they are both assigned with what I put into those two rich text boxes is this what you mean? Thanks for your help by the way, I really appreciate this, I'm a noob at programming and just trying to better myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has now been fixed and everything works as expected my problem was this:

```
Form1 welcomeForm
```

and in my Form_Load event handler

```
welcomeForm = new Form1();
```

Every time I was adding new tasks to the list, is was creating a new form to go over it, thus it was not saving to the list correctly. So it went from this:

```
welcomeForm.TasksArray.Add(new taskStructure
            {
                taskName = taskNameRTB.Text,
                taskDescription = taskDescRTB.Text
            });
```

To:

```
taskStructure.TasksArray.Add(new taskStructure
            {
                taskName = taskNameRTB.Text,
                taskDescription = taskDescRTB.Text
            });

        foreach (taskStructure singletask in taskStructure.TasksArray)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(singletask.ToString());
        }
```

I have added that class and the list to a separate class file to help keep the code looking cleaner, and thus changed the code accordingly ^. The tasks now save correctly, and the list works as expected. I would like to really thank everyone for the help and advice, and because of this help I will not hesitate to use this again as I have learnt a lot from my two questions alone!

Answer (score 0):

Using the provided code, I am getting the expected behaviour of different values per item.
Please check that when you are testing the code, that you change the values that you are retrieving from `taskNameRTB.Text` and `taskDescRTB.Text`

I tested the code with:

```
  welcomeForm.TasksArray.Add(new Form1.taskStructure
  {
    taskName = "SomeName1",
    taskDescription = "SomeDesc1"
  });

  welcomeForm.TasksArray.Add(new Form1.taskStructure
  {
    taskName = "SomeName2",
    taskDescription = "SomeDesc2"
  });
```

Below is an example of overriding the `ToString()` method for the `taskStructure` class, this helps with outputting the information to the user.

```
public class taskStructure
{
  public string taskName { get; set; }
  public string taskDescription { get; set; }
  public int Priority { get; set; }
  public string dateAndTime { get; set; }

  public override string ToString()
  {
    // This can be changed to output any form of string that you want your object to represent
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    output.AppendLine(String.Format("taskName: {0}", taskName));
    output.AppendLine(String.Format("taskDescription: {0}", taskDescription));
    output.AppendLine(String.Format("Priority: {0}", Priority));
    output.AppendLine(String.Format("dateAndTime: {0}", dateAndTime));
    return output.ToString();
  }
}
```

That `ToString()` then allows the below code to replace the different `MessabeBoxshow()` that you have

```
  foreach (Form1.taskStructure singleTask in welcomeForm.TasksArray)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(singleTask.ToString());
  }
```

Comment: I have tried what you have stated above and when I change it to:

`welcomeForm.TasksArray.Add(new Form1.taskStructure
                {
                    taskName = "Bob",
                    taskDescription = "Marley"
                });

            welcomeForm.TasksArray.Add(new Form1.taskStructure
            {
                taskName = "Kieran",
                taskDescription = "Lowe"
            });`

It works! However, I want where it says "Bob", "Marley" etc. to be taskNameRTB.Text, etc. and when I change it to this, the first stuff I enter comes up twice due to the two Add()'s.

Comment: That would be because of the double call to `Add()`. Also see Maria's answer, that is a very important change that you might need to make

Comment: I'm thinking that too, but I don't know how I could rectify that. I also made their change and added it just under the partial class that is created for the form, shown below:

`public partial class addTask : Form
    {
        Form1 welcomeForm = new Form1();
        public addTask()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void addTask_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I have to post this as an answer. I just wanted to add that if you want to add tasks to the existing list on every click of the button (which I assume you do), you should move this line

```
Form1 welcomeForm = new Form1();
```

outside of the button click event handler, for example to the onload event handler, because now on every click you create a new form which creates a new empty list and what you've added on the previous click will be lost.

Edit: Try that

```
public partial class addTask : Form 
{ 
    Form1 welcomeForm; 

    public addTask() { InitializeComponent(); } 

    private void addTask_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
         welcomeForm = new Form1();
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't move it to the onload form, or do you mean onload button? I tried that anyway and it still shows both of the Add() methods holding the same value I enter for the first Add().

e.g. First Add() = Test Man
then it send "Test Man" straight to the second add. Which I want them to be different. Thanks for your help though! Really appreciate it!

Comment: I have tried your edit and no errors happen at start up, but still when I enter values for the first Add() in my Rich Text Boxes, they also pass over to the second Add(), which I don't want them to do. Thanks for your continued help! :D

Comment: I edited my answer with the code. If you take the values from the textboxes it's normal they are the same- the textbox value hasn't changed. Try adding just one task on every button click, and change the textbox text between clicks and see if that works.

Comment: I have just tried that and once the form closes, and then I click the button again, the values I enter before are now in the Rich Text Boxes at form start up. But when I remove them and enter something new, only one task shows up (The latest one entered) and not the previous one I entered before.

Comment: This is how it is done through override thanks to @BerndLinde:

`public override string ToString()
            {
                StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
                output.AppendLine(String.Format("Task Name: {0}", taskName));
                output.AppendLine(String.Format("Task Description: {0}", taskDescription));
                output.AppendLine(String.Format("Task Priority Level: {0}", Priority));
                output.AppendLine(String.Format("Task Date and Time Completion Date: {0}", dateAndTime));
                return output.ToString();
            }`

Comment: This is how I loop through them:

`foreach (Form1.taskStructure singletask in welcomeForm.TasksArray)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(singletask.ToString());
            }`

Comment: Idk... Try to debug it and see what exactly is going on

Comment: No problem :) If you need any more help I'd be happy to try